# Amazon route 53 CNAME records not validating on Sendgrid

Tags: dns, sendgrid, amazon-route53

I have an EC2 instance running on AWS that is hosting a Rails app. I am trying to allow this Rails app to receive incoming email. I am using Sendgrid as a mail server. I am stuck in the Domain Authentication step. Sendgrid requires that I set up three CNAME records in my name server so that when an email is aimed at my domain, it instead goes to Sendgrid. I have started trying to use AWS Route 53 to configure my DNS server, but nothing is working. The page I am looking at on Sengrid says the following. I've changed the numbers for security:

```
You will need to install the following records to complete the process.

TYPE: CNAME
HOST: em7142.ec2-18-219-142-93.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com  
VALUE: u15663989.wl250.sendgrid.net 
STATUS: Failed

TYPE: CNAME
HOST: s1._domainkey.ec2-18-219-142-93.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com   
VALUE: s1.domainkey.u15663989.wl250.sendgrid.net    
STATUS: Failed

TYPE:CNAME
HOST: s2._domainkey.ec2-18-219-142-93.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com   
VALUE: s2.domainkey.u15663989.wl250.sendgrid.net    
STATUS: Failed
```

...and these are the records I've added to my AWS Route 53:

```
Name: s1._domainkey.ec2-18-219-142-93.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
Type: CNAME
Value: s1.domainkey.u15663989.wl250.sendgrid.net

Name: s2._domainkey.ec2-18-219-142-93.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
Type: CNAME
Value: s2.domainkey.u15663989.wl250.sendgrid.net

Name: em7142.ec2-18-219-142-93.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
Type: CNAME
Value: u15663989.wl250.sendgrid.net
```

Whenever I click `Verify` on the Sendgrid page, I still get failures. Also, when I used the `dig` tool to query the CNAME records, I get nothing back in the ANSWER section. Not sure why this could be.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

In a closely-related situation, SendGrid domain verification failed for me when working with Route53. As it turned out, when adding records such as the following to Route53

```
Record Name:            s1._domainkey.mywebsite.com
Type.                   CNAME
Value/Route Traffic To: s1.domainkey.u12345678.wl910.sendgrid.net
```

when a record name of `s1._domainkey.mywebsite.com` was entered, Route53 was expecting a subdomain, and used the following in the DNS record: `s1._domainkey.mywebsite.com.mywebsite.com`.

This was fixed by using only the subdomain `s1._domainkey`, which resulted in a record name of `s1._domainkey.mywebsite.com`; thereafter, SendGrid verification was successful.

Comment: Did you also added em3018.example.com with the value of u14921173.wl177.sendgrid.net ? I did and still after 48 hours it gives me this error: Expected CNAME for "em3018.example.com" to match "u14921173.wl177.sendgrid.net". No idea how to solve this 